# Failure to get bash completions when using the optcomplete module

Tags: python, bash-completion

I am trying to use **`python-optcomplete`** package (**1.2-11.1** from Debian Testing):

```
$ cat /etc/bash_completion.d/optcomplete 
_optcomplete()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $( \
    COMP_LINE=$COMP_LINE  COMP_POINT=$COMP_POINT \
    COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}"  COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
    OPTPARSE_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
}
$ source /etc/bash_completion.d/optcomplete 
$ complete -F _optcomplete optcomplete-test
$ pwd
/tmp/examples
$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wena wena 3490 Feb 24 23:25 optcomplete-conditional
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wena wena 3521 Feb 24 23:25 optcomplete-simple
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/tmp/examples
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/tmp/examples
$ optcomplete-simple -[TAB][TAB]
```

I get nothing when trying to complete... am not as lucky as [this guy](http://furius.ca/optcomplete/doc/sample-output.html).

Here's the (snipped) code [as taken from the project website](http://furius.ca/optcomplete/bin/optcomplete-simple) (filename: "optcomplete-simple"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import optparse, optcomplete

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-s', '--simple', action='store_true',
                      help="Simple really simple option without argument.")
    parser.add_option('-o', '--output', action='store',
                      help="Option that requires an argument.")
    opt = parser.add_option('-p', '--script', action='store',
                            help="Option that takes python scripts args only.")
    opt.completer = optcomplete.RegexCompleter('.*\.py')
    optcomplete.autocomplete(parser, ['.*\.tar.*'])
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're binding the completion script to `optcomplete-test`, but are testing with `optcomplete-simple`. Use this instead:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/optcomplete
complete -F _optcomplete optcomplete-simple
```

Note (just in case) that changing `$PATH` isn't strictly necessary. You can run the script via its absolute path or as `./optcomplete-simple` and have the completion work. Also, the standard way to add a directory to the current `$PATH` is this:

```
export PATH=/new/directory:$PATH
```

Comment: A little embarassing. Also, thanks for the tip about the PATH. And indeed I changed the PATH because I was worried that it would not be recognized.

Comment: No problem! Also, I actually made the exact same mistake in the first version of my answer :)